# What to do when maSigPro is not working in R?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to use maSigPro according to the User manual with the supplied sample data sets in R. However, when running the maSigPro function it tells me that it could not find it, although I have installed it via Bioconductor. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
> BiocManager::install("maSigPro", update = TRUE)
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see
'help("repositories", package = "BiocManager")' for details.
Replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/
Bioconductor version 3.18 (BiocManager 1.30.22), R 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Old packages: 'DESeq2'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
a
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.18/bioc/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/DESeq2_1.41.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2852511 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in



/var/folders/_c/bdqcq29n38lgsz935x02b0pr0000gq/T//Rtmpr0ETrC/downloaded_packages
Warning message:
package(s) not installed when version(s) same as or greater than current;
  use `force = TRUE` to re-install: 'maSigPro' 
> library("maSigPro")
> ts.analysis <- maSigPro(data.abiotic, edesign.abiotic)
Error in maSigPro(data.abiotic, edesign.abiotic) : 
  could not find function "maSigPro"
```

I already tried quitting R, uninstalling and reinstalling maSigPro.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a `maSigPro` function in the maSigPro package. Are you sure that you are following the user guide correctly?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am, as it's basically just copying and pasting. Even the guide says that the function should be included in the package:"The analysis approach implemented in maSigPro is executed in 5 major steps which are run by the package core functions make.design.matrix(), p.vector(), T.fit(), get.siggenes() and see.genes(). Additionally, the package provides the wrapping function maSigPro() which executes the entire analysis in one go."

Comment: But you're right, the function is not present in the package (I checked), although I have no idea why.